# multiple speakers multiple sounds in ubuntu

Tags: audio, ubuntu-20.04

My PC has two different audio outputs. One built in, another on LCD monitor connected through HDMI. I want to play different sounds in different speakers not semulteniously. Like if the LCD monitor has `videos` opened, the sound will pass over the HDMI. If built in display opens another application that plays sound, it will play in the built in speakers. How to do that in ubuntu or any Linux?

Comment: FYI. Its better to ask this on superuser.com. This is not programming related question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `pulseaudio` handler solved the problem.